# Is there any better way to understand angular error/exception messages in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

During development we often encounter errors/exceptions in developer console. But for me its not easy recognize the error properly (:P ).
Is there any better way to get more information about error/exception like due to which code, line number, which line etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use Chrome for debugging. In Chrome the Angular messages are displayed as a nice stracktrace with a clickable link to the error description.

You can also use the non-minified version of angular to get more descriptive error messages.